# make absolute div that appears above relative anchor tag (img inside) both clickable

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to get a hidden div, that appears above a anchor tag (while hovering), both clickable. The link contains an image and clicking it opens a modal box, and the div has social network links/images.

The parent is `<figure>` and the children are, in order, the `<a>` link with the `<img>` inside (both `relative`), the hidden div (`absolute`) and a `<figcaption>` (`relative`) that is the one above the hidden div and must remain like that until it hover and the div appears from the top.

I wonder why the `z-index` value of +0 doesn't work with `absolute`. It must be -1 or less to be behind the `<figcaption>` container. Some other tiny detail that bothers me: the top `a`/`img` outline border while focused is not visible with my code (see the fiddle at the end). What makes it so? Both have `display: block` and `position: relative`.

I'm using html5 tags, so:

```
<figure class="team-grid twenny">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#t1_desc">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/205x264" />
    </a>
    <div class="p-mask">
        <ul class="social-icons">
            <li><a href="#" class="icon-button twitter"><i class="icon-twitter"></i><span></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icon-button google"><i class="icon-google"></i><span></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icon-button v"><i class="icon-v"></i><span></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icon-button pinterest"><i class="pinterest"></i><span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <figcaption>
        <h4>Natasha César</h4>
        <p><?= $lang->getW('t1_title') ?></p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

The social network links should have 30px (for both width and height). The design is from a w3layout template (fiddle with the original code: https://jsfiddle.net/bfb1L7g1/ <-- **this is what I want to achieve with simple html5 markup**)

This is the css code:

```
.team-grid { position: relative }
.team figure {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block
}
.team figure a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.team figure img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.team figcaption {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 4px double #D0D0D0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
}
.team .p-mask {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72);
    bottom: 30%;
    padding: 1em 0 .6em;
    width: 87%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 100%, 0px );
       -moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 100%, 0px );
        -ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 100%, 0px );
         -o-transform: translate3d( 0px, 100%, 0px );
            transform: translate3d( 0px, 100%, 0px );
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease 0s;
       -moz-transition: all .5s ease 0s;
            transition: all .5s ease 0s;
}
.team figure:hover .p-mask {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, 0px );
       -moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, 0px );
        -ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, 0px );
         -o-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, 0px );
            transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, 0px );
}
```

Why is the `absolute` `div` above the `figcaption` element if this has `z-index: 2` (1 more than the div)?

I have made a jsfiddle with the rest of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/cm3k6rot/1/

So the `div.p-mask` is exactly the same in both jsfiddles (html and css), why is behaving different? Does anyone see where's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different values of `position` in CSS affects it's vertical alignment.

> The z-index property in CSS controls the vertical stacking order of
>   elements that overlap. As in, which one appears as if it is physically
>   closer to you. z-index only effects elements that have a position
>   value other than static (the default).
>
> Elements can overlap for a variety of reasons, for instance relative
>   positioning has nudged it over something else. Negative margin has
>   pulled the element over another. Absolutely positioned elements
>   overlap each other. All sorts of reasons.

If you have two divs, and one is absolutely positioned and one isn't, no amount of z-index on the `position: static;` div is going to change anything.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 2147483647;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1" style="position: absolute;"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

But if both the divs are abosolutely positioned, then even a very small `z-index` value will do place it above the other div:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

You can read more about `z-index` [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)

Comment: Lol so why does it work if I make the `figcaption` element `position: relative`? I just noticed. Give it to `div2` to see if it's not a mistake. Edit: not a mistake: https://jsfiddle.net/uasfgae1/

Comment: There, now it makes sense. Thanks!